# How to decode this json in Firebase realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
void readData() {
            databaseReference
                .child("data")
                .child("chapters")
                .once()
                .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
              print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
        
            });
```

> This is my read data function and I  got the following JSON output.

```
[
          {
            "name": "Global Village",
            "videolists": [
              {
                "title": "Binary to decimal",
                "link": "http://..........",
                "duration": "5:3"
              },
              {
                "title": "Binary to decimal",
                "link": "http://..........",
                "duration": "5:3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Data Communication and Networking",
            "videolists": [
              {
                "title": "Binary to decimal",
                "link": "http://..........",
                "duration": "5:3"
              },
              {
                "title": "Binary to decimal",
                "link": "http://..........",
                "duration": "5:3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

**I have tried to decode the JSON using this code**

var lists= json.decode(snapshot.value) as List<dynamic>;

**But I got an error like this**

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'String'

**How can I decode the JSON?**

Comment: May you please post your desired output?

Comment: @ Squ1rr3lz I just want to store json decoded value in a varable  as a list. Later I will use this as function argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 Iterable lists     = json.decode(result);
  List<dynamic> map = lists.toList();
  map.forEach((res){
    print(res["videolists"][0]);
  });
```

[`json.decode()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html) takes a `String` and returns a `dynamic`, therefore we can assign it to class `Iterable` and then we can use `toList()` to create a list and iterate using `forEach()`. The above should give you:

```
{title: Binary to decimal, link: http://.........., duration: 5:3}
{title: Binary to decimal, link: http://.........., duration: 5:3}
```

Comment: still I am face this error " [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"